# return Promise Pending, and its fullfilled, but not returning the json

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await

I am calling a local json file using fetch and aync and await, but when I call this all I see in the console is the Promise pending and in it showing the state as fulfilled and not the json data.

The code is

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    const jData = ReturnJSONData();
    
    console.log(jData);
});


async function ReturnJSONData() {
    const data = await fetch("../TreeListData.json");
    const ds = await data.json();
    return ds;
}
```

In the async function the returning ds has the json in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`async` functions *always* return promises. If you need to interact with the value inside that promise, either call `.then` on that promise:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    const promise = ReturnJSONData();
    promise.then(jData => {
      console.log(jData);
    });
});
```

or put your code in an `async` function and `await` the promise.

```
$(document).ready(async () => {
    const jData = await ReturnJSONData();
    console.log(jData);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `fetch` is async, which means you need to await it.

```
$(document).ready(async () => {
    const jData = await ReturnJSONData();
    
    console.log(jData);
});


async function ReturnJSONData() {
    const data = await fetch("../TreeListData.json");
    const ds = await data.json();
    return ds;
}
```

To demo this working with a dummy async call:

```js
$(document).ready( async ()=>{
  await dummyPromise();
  console.log("done")
})

const dummyPromise = async () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,2000))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```